# Partition data around a match query during aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate, partitioning, mongo-java

What I have been trying to get my head around is to perform some kind of partitioning(split by predicate) in a mongo query. My current query looks like:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
 {"$match": { $and:[ {$or:[{"toggled":false},{"toggled":true, "status":"INACTIVE"}]}  ,  {"updatedAt":{$gte:1549786260000}} ] }},
 {"$unwind" :"$interests"},
 {"$group" : {"_id": {"iid": "$interests", "pid":"$publisher"}, "count": {"$sum" : 1}}},
 {"$project":{ _id: 0, "iid": "$_id.iid", "pid": "$_id.pid", "count": 1 }}
])
```

This results in the following output:

```
{
    "count" : 3.0,
    "iid" : "INT456",
    "pid" : "P789"
}
{
    "count" : 2.0,
    "iid" : "INT789",
    "pid" : "P789"
}
{
    "count" : 1.0,
    "iid" : "INT123",
    "pid" : "P789"
}
{
    "count" : 1.0,
    "iid" : "INT123",
    "pid" : "P123"
}
```

---

All good so far, but then I had realized that for the documents that match the specific filter `{"toggled":true, "status":"INACTIVE"}`, I would rather **decrement the count (-1)**. (considering the eventual value can be negative as well.)

Is there a way to somehow partition the data after `match` to make sure different `grouping` operations are performed for both the collection of documents?

Something that sounds similar to what I am looking for is
[`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/#exp._S_mergeObjects), or maybe [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#exp._S_reduce), but not much that I can relate from the documentation examples.

***Note***: I can sense, one straightforward way to deal with this would be to perform two queries, but I am looking for a single query to perform the operation.

---

Sample documents for the above output would be:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1f7******"),
    "id" : "CON123",
    "title" : "Game",
    "content" : {},
    "status" : "ACTIVE",
    "toggle":false,
    "publisher" : "P789",
    "interests" : [ 
        "INT456"
    ],
    "updatedAt" : NumberLong(1582078628264)
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1f8******"),
    "id" : "CON456",
    "title" : "Home",
    "content" : {},
    "status" : "INACTIVE",
    "toggle":true,
    "publisher" : "P789",
    "interests" : [ 
        "INT456",
        "INT789"
    ],
    "updatedAt" : NumberLong(1582078628264)
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d0e9******"),
    "id" : "CON654",
    "title" : "School",
    "content" : {},
    "status" : "ACTIVE",
    "toggle":false,
    "publisher" : "P789",
    "interests" : [ 
        "INT123",
        "INT456",
        "INT789"
    ],
    "updatedAt" : NumberLong(1582078628264)
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d207*******"),
    "id" : "CON789",
    "title":"Stack",
    "content" : { },
    "status" : "ACTIVE",
    "toggle":false,
    "publisher" : "P123",
    "interests" : [ 
        "INT123"
    ],
    "updatedAt" : NumberLong(1582078628264)
}
```

---

What I am looking forward to as a result though is

```
{
    "count" : 1.0, (2-1)
    "iid" : "INT456",
    "pid" : "P789"
}
{
    "count" : 0.0, (1-1)
    "iid" : "INT789",
    "pid" : "P789"
}
{
    "count" : 1.0,
    "iid" : "INT123",
    "pid" : "P789"
}
{
    "count" : 1.0,
    "iid" : "INT123",
    "pid" : "P123"
}
```

Comment: You can try using the [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html) pipeline stage.

Comment: @prasad_ consider making an answer? In the meanwhiile I would update the question with sample documents as asked by whoami.

Comment: I posted an answer using the facets. But, I might refine it further little later on and update the query (in terms of code, not the function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This aggregation gives the desired result.

```
db.posts.aggregate( [
{ $match:  { updatedAt: { $gte: 1549786260000 } } },
{ $facet: {
        FALSE: [
            { $match: { toggle: false } },
            { $unwind : "$interests" },
            { $group : { _id : { iid: "$interests", pid: "$publisher" }, count: { $sum : 1 } } },
        ],
        TRUE: [
            { $match: { toggle: true, status: "INACTIVE" } },
            { $unwind : "$interests" },
            { $group : { _id : { iid: "$interests", pid: "$publisher" }, count: { $sum : -1 } } },
        ]
} },
{ $project: { result: { $concatArrays: [ "$FALSE", "$TRUE" ] } } },
{ $unwind: "$result" },
{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$result" } },
{ $group : { _id : "$_id", count: { $sum : "$count" } } },
{ $project:{ _id: 0, iid: "$_id.iid", pid: "$_id.pid", count: 1 } }
] )
```

[ EDIT ADD ]

The output from the query using the input data from the question post:

```
{ "count" : 1, "iid" : "INT123", "pid" : "P789" }
{ "count" : 1, "iid" : "INT123", "pid" : "P123" }
{ "count" : 0, "iid" : "INT789", "pid" : "P789" }
{ "count" : 1, "iid" : "INT456", "pid" : "P789" }
```

---

[ EDIT ADD 2 ]

This query gets the same result with different approach (code):

```
db.posts.aggregate( [
  { 
      $match:  { updatedAt: { $gte: 1549786260000 } } 
  },
  { 
      $unwind : "$interests" 
  },
  { 
      $group : { 
          _id : { 
              iid: "$interests", 
              pid: "$publisher" 
          }, 
          count: { 
              $sum: {
                  $switch: {
                      branches: [
                        { case: { $eq: [ "$toggle", false ] },
                           then: 1 },
                        { case: { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$toggle", true] },  { $eq: [ "$status", "INACTIVE" ] } ] },
                           then: -1 }
                      ]
                  }          
              } 
          }
      } 
  },
  { 
      $project:{
           _id: 0, 
           iid: "$_id.iid", 
           pid: "$_id.pid", 
           count: 1 
      } 
  }
] )
```

[ EDIT ADD 3 ]

**NOTE:**

The facet query runs the two facets (TRUE and FALSE) on the same set of documents; it is like two queries running in parallel. But, there is some duplication of code as well as additional stages for shaping the documents down the pipeline to get the desired output.

The second query avoids the code duplication, and there are much lesser stages in the aggregation pipeline. This will make difference when the input dataset has a large number of documents to process - in terms of performance.  In general, lesser stages means lesser iterations of the documents (as a stage has to scan the documents which are output from the previous stage).

Comment: You are right about your comment about the `count`. I had posted the wrong version of the code. I updated the answer to the corrected one.

Comment: I added another version of the code with same results. This one doesn't use the facets.

Comment: The updated query works. I would spend some more time around learning `facets`. Any performance impacts as compared to the normal `match`, `unwind`, `group` and `project` flow?

Comment: Check my newer version of code; it is efficient than the first version.

Comment: Could you explain in the answer, why is the latter efficient that the former? I can confirm anyway both of them work (+1) functionally.

Comment: I added the note about code efficiency (it is in general), and also updated the second version of the code to _remove_ one more stage (the `$addFields`) and incorporate that logic in the `$group` stage's `$sum` operation.

Comment: Sure. Also from the [documentation of switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/), it's worth remembering that switch would fail for cases not specified. Using `default` would be safe in such cases. e.g `"default":0` for my current use case

Comment: For cases not specified the `"default": 0` will do fine. Also, it is documentation.