# Mongo query union of two average results based on different field value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following structure for my `player_statistics` collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e712989edbdba067fed5f2e"),
    "surname" : "player_A",
    "team" : "team_A",
    "position" : "forward",
    "minutes" : 46,
    "shots" : 2,
    "passes" : 16,
    "tackles" : 0,
    "saves" : 0
}
```

The property `position` has multiple values such as `forward`, `midfield` etc. My requirement is to retrieve average passes based on the position **using one query**.

```
db.player_statistics.aggregate([
    { $match: { position: 'forward'} },
         { $group: {"_id": null , pop :{$avg:'$passes'}} } 
  ]).pretty();

db.player_statistics.aggregate([
    { $match: { position: 'midfielder'} },
    { $group: {"_id": null , pop2 :{$avg:'$passes'}} } ,
  ]).pretty();
```

I wrote the following two based on mongo aggregate. Is there a way to combine the two into one, using something similar to **`UNION`** in MySQL. Or is there a better way of achieving this ?

Comment: You can try one of the two approaches from this post's answer: [Partition data around a match query during aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285951/partition-data-around-a-match-query-during-aggregation).

Answer (score 2):

In that case all you've to do is to group on `position` field :

```
db.player_statistics.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$position",
      pop: {
        $avg: "$passes"
      }
    }
  },
  /** Optional - When you use '$avg' then result might not be integer can be a decimal to make it to int you can use round */
  {
    $addFields: {
      pop: {
        $round: "$pop"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gjvE8WjBkZ_)

Comment: This helped me to arrive at my final answer.

Comment: @CoolCK : Ok if you need only for two `positions` out of many then `$match` as you've done should work :-)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @whoami I was able to write the needed MongoDB query.

```
db.player_statistics.aggregate([
   { $match : { $or : [{position:{$eq:'midfielder'}}, {position:{$eq:'forward'}}]}},
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$position",
      avg: {
        $avg: "$passes"
      }
    }
  }
])
```