# Merging multiple aggregation queries to one with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I'm using these three queries to can have a python dataframe format with the columns : 'Date', '% part of business 2', '% part of business 3'. (for each day to have the percentage of gain from business 2 and 3).

```
query_business2 = collection.aggregate( [
        {
          '$match': {'Business': 2}      
        },
        {
                '$group': {
                        '_id': '$Date',
                        'stab2': {'$sum': '$Money'}
                }
        },
        {
                '$sort': {'_id': 1}
        }
        ])
query_business3 = collection.aggregate([
        {
                '$match': {'Business':3}
        },
        {
                '$group': {
                        '_id': '$Date',
                        'stab3': {'$sum': '$Money'}
                        }
        },
        {
                '$sort': {'_id': 1}
        }
        ])
query_total = collection.aggregate([
        {
                '$group': {
                        '_id': '$Date',
                        'total': {'$sum': '$Money'}
                        }
        },
        {
                '$sort': {'_id': 1}
        }
        ])
```

For this to be faster, I would like to merge these three queries into one. I tried using '$or' but didn't work for unashable dict.
Is there a better way to do that ? It might be possible to directly make the dataframe format without using pandas after this queries and to calculate directly the percentage of each business compared to the total money earned. Thank you for your help

Comment: Here are couple of posts with similar question and answers: [Aggregate and sum by one key and rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60311604/aggregate-and-sum-by-one-key-and-rest/60311771#60311771) _and_ 
[Partition data around a match query during aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285951/partition-data-around-a-match-query-during-aggregation/60292537#60292537).

Comment: Thank you, it was hard for me to find precise help about this problem but with $cond I will probably be able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to prasad_ the answer is :

```
query_business = collection.aggregate([
        {
            '$group':{
                    '_id': '$Date',
                    'total_2': {'$sum' : {'$cond': [{'$eq': ['$Business', 2]}, '$Money', 0]}},
                    'total_3': {'$sum' : {'$cond': [{'$eq': ['$Business', 3]}, '$Money', 0]}},
                    'total': {'$sum': '$Money'},
                    }
        },
        {
            '$match': {'$and': [{ 'total_2': {'$gt': 0}}, {'total': {'$gt': 0}},{'total_3':{'$gt':0}}]}     
        },
        {
            '$addFields':{
                    'part_2': { "$multiply": [ { "$divide": ["$total_2","$total"] }, 100 ] },
                    'part_3': { "$multiply": [{'$divide': ['$total_3','$total']}, 100]}
                    }
        }
        ])
```